# where to use cost function in simple linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning and I've studied the math behind cost functions. I want to know where to implement the cost function for linear regression, i.e. J(B1, B2) = 1/2nΣ(y-y_pred)^2  ?

In the code below there is no cost function use because we calculate cost function after predict value. When I go through the code, I don't see any error. minimisation steps. 
The code is available [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-regression-python-implementation/)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def estimate_coef(X, y):

    n = np.size(X)

    m_X, m_y = np.mean(X), np.mean(y)

    SS_Xy = np.sum(y*X) - n*m_y*m_X
    SS_XX = np.sum(X*X) - n*m_X*m_X

    b_1 = SS_Xy / SS_XX

    b_0 = m_y - b_1*m_X

    return (b_0, b_1)

def plot_regression_line(X, y, b):
    n = np.size(X)
    plt.scatter(X, y, color = "m", 
               marker = "o", s = 30) 
    y_pred = b[0] + b[1]*X
    print(f'prediction=>{y_pred}')
    plt.plot(X, y_pred, color = "g")
    plt.xlabel('x') 
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show() 

def main(): 
    # observations 
    X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) 
    y = np.array([1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 12]) 

    # estimating coefficients 
    b = estimate_coef(X, y) 
    print(f'b_0=>{b[0]}, b_1=>{b[1]}') 



    # plotting regression line 
    plot_regression_line(X, y, b) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: Vasim, please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: ok i will mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimisation that needs to be solved is in terms of b0 and b1, i.e. we need to find the optimal value of both. When you solve that minimisation problem, you arrive at  `b_1 = SS_Xy / SS_XX` and `b_0 = m_y - b_1*m_X`. Instead of solving the minimization in code, they have used the results directly to get the optimal value. This has been mentioned in the article:

> Our task is to find the value of b_0 and b_1 for which J(b_0,b_1) is minimum!
>
> Without going into the mathematical details, we present the result here: